# Print out to a div in the view from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a div block in my view like this:

```
   <div id="divStatus" style="margin-top:10px;width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;">
   </div>
```

then from the view, user clicks on a button that calls the controller. In the controller some tasks are executed so from the controller I want to update a div block within the view. In this div I print out phrasses.

How to do this?

example:

```
public ActionResult()
    {
        // Do something
    Update_DIV_in_View("some thing has been done"); <--- DIV in the view must be updated by appending this message

    // Do another thing
    Update_DIV_in_VIEW("another thing has been done");<--- DIV in the view must be updated by appending this message

    .... and so on

    // All things done
    Update_DIV_in_VIEW("All things have been done");<--- DIV in the view must be updated by appending this message

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a second action in your controller which only shows the updated content of the div and on your normal page when you press the button load the status with an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call (for example the [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

1. In your view use `Ajax Form` as follows:

   ```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "beforeSubmitFunction()", HttpMethod = "POST",UpdateTargetId = "divStatus", OnComplete = "InsertRow()" }))
   {
     .. //your Html form Controls
   }

   function beforeSubmitFunction()
   {
       //Your code for before submitting...
   }
   ```
2. Then in your controller return your partial view as result which will get updated in your div with id `divStatus`

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(TypeName model)
   {
       return PartialView("PartialViewName", model);
   }
   ```

Comment: As I has said to @Florian you also update the control in the view once action in the controller has finished and return to the view but in my case I want to update the control in the view during the action is done its jobs (see my comment for @Florian).

Comment: But as I understand now you updates the control before it begins. But imagine you are within the action in the controller: action does a thing (but action has not finished yet) so it prints "first thing done" to the div in the view, next thing is done so this is printed in the div (append) in the view, and so on, finally the action finishes its job and do a return View(). It cannot be done with your approach.See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 examples what I am using:

**example 1:**

button (here with telerik css styling):

```
<a class="t-button t-button-icontext" onclick="ajaxCreateEquipment()"><span
    class="t-icon t-add"></span>Create</a>
```

javascript: **#equipment-table-container** is the id of the target div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxCreateEquipment() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowCreate", "Equipment")',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#equipment-table-container').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

EquipmentController.cs:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowCreate()
{
    // some calculation code, fetch model from DB something else
    ViewData.Add("FormAction", "Create"); // some ViewData
    return PartialView("Create", model); // returns the View html file
}
```

**example 2:**
function call here with id argument and Json return:

```
@{
    var supplierQuoteId = Model.ID.ToString();
    <a id="@supplierQuoteId" onclick="updateDiv(this.id)"></a>
}
```

javascript:

```
function updateDiv(id) {
    var strUrl = "/LicenseTerm/UpdateUsedQuantity/" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: strUrl,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#licenseterm-usedquantity').html(data.sum);
        }
    });
}
```

LicenseTermController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult UpdateUsedQuantity(Guid id)
{
    var licenseTerm = _repository.GetAll<LicenseTerm>().Where(l => l.ID == id).First();
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (LicenseAllocation l in licenseTerm.LicenseAllocations.Where(o => o.Deleted == false))
        sum = sum + l.LicenseQuantity;
    return Json(new { sum = sum }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**example 3: simple get**

```
function ajaxFieldDefinitionCreate(id) {
    var strUrl = '/FieldDefinition/Create' + '/' + id.toString() + '?isRefreshAction=true';
    $.get(strUrl, function (data) {
        $('#equipmenttype-fielddefinition-createeditarea').html(data);
    });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(Guid id, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(false)] bool isRefreshAction)
{
    var equipmentType = _equipmentTypeRepository.GetById(id);
    var fieldDefinitionDto = new FieldDefinitionDto
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
        ParentName = equipmentType.Name,
    };
    return PartialView("Create", fieldDefinitionDto);
}
```

Comment: As seen your example I think I have not explained well. In your example you update the control in the view after the task in the controller has finished. But in my case, the controller has not finished its task. The controller does some things, when one thing is finished I want to print a message in the div, then the controller continues doing next thing, and when another thing is finished, I want to print a message in the div again (append) and so on. When all things are done in the controller, then the controller returns the view or the result.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the changes of the question, especially that the questioner would like to have more returns in the same Action:

- the **concept** of HTTP request is to transmit relatively small pieces of data from the server to the client, which invoked the e.g. HTTP GET request.

You **can not keep open** the HTTP GET request for more transmissions.

I searched the web and extracted that especially HTML5 will address this requirement with the HTTP stream, but this is another topic. e.g.: I got this url: http://socket.io/ .

**Bypass:**

But as an idea of mine,
I would make a first ajax call to determine the count of the next requests, addressed in the controller Action1.
And then invoke several new requests in the success part of the first ajax request, with the url of the Action2, e.g. Calculate etc., which appends then the several pieces of data to the div content.

here some quickly invented javascript code:

```
function updateDiv() {
    var strUrl = "/Home/RequestCount/";            
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: strUrl,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (count) {
            var strUrlCalc = "/Home/Calc/";
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: strUrlCalc,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#test').append(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });                      
}
```